# Why is my array (5 elements) changing size dynamically?

Tags: java, arrays

I have declared a `String` array.

```
String[] csvColumns = new String[5];
```

However, when reading from a `CSV` file:

```
     String[] csvColumns = new String[5];  // Explicitly including this declaration again in case Stack Overflow users need to see the scope of the variable.
     String row;  // Will receive each column of 1 line at a time of the CSV file.
     while ((row = inFile.readLine()) != null)  // BufferedReader used to parse CSV File.
        {
        csvColumns = row.split(",");  // Each element of the array will recieve the value of each column.
        // Initialise class attributes with each column.
        }
```

If a column in a line of the `CSV` file doesn't contain any values (in my file this can only ever be the case for the last column, because the column isn't mandatory and contains notes about a particular issue) then `csvColumns` reduces its size by 1.  I don't see how this is possible if I'm using an array - but then again, I'm a novice programmer.

Any reason why this could happen?

Edit* Thanks to both answers, very helpful.  Should have checked the return type of the method `split`!  (Thanks @chrylis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `csvColumns` isn't static (it appears to be a local variable), and second, it's a *variable*, not an array. You're reassigning the value (an array reference) to be the reference to the new array returned by `split`. (That old `String[5]` you created and never used now has nothing pointing to it and will be garbage collected.)

Comment: Thanks.  I was under the impression that the term for an array of this type was called a "static array" - silly.

Comment: Making it clear about the return type of 'split' really was brilliant, just understanding that now - as there was no 'new' operator, but didn't think to check return type of 'split'

Answer (score 3):

The array doesn't change it's size. You just create a new array by this line

```
csvColumns = row.split(",")
```

and assign it to the `csvColumns` variable.

And the old `new String[5]` array will be garbage-collected because it is not referenced by any variables anymore.

You can change

```
String[] csvColumns = new String[5];
```

to

```
String[] csvColumns = null;
```

And your code will still work because you never use the created array. You use just **variable**.

Comment: Even the `null` assignment shouldn't be necessary, because it gets assigned in the loop before reading.

Comment: Yes, but it is the best practice to explicitly initialize variable with a value (even `null`). But of course it is a code-style question. I explicitly assigned it here to make it more clear to the OP to understand what is going on.

Comment: A lot of programmers have been trained for decades to initialize variables to something in case of "accidents", but I've never been happy with that.  In Java, it actually makes less sense than in other languages, because Java has rules that try to prevent a variable from being used before it's initialized, and the compiler will catch cases when you do.  If you initialize variables to a meaningless value, then the compiler won't catch it, and that could make it longer to detect coding errors of this nature.  So I'd actually call this a "worst practice" in Java.

Comment: @ajb I never thought about it: "If you initialize variables to a meaningless value, then the compiler won't catch it". So, I think you are right here! At least for local variables.